# What's the difference between hydroponics and aeroponics?

Tags: identification

I do know how hydroponics works. I think aeroponics is just like cloning but in a big scale you just have to use big buckets and keep air and water at all times with chemicals .

Answer (score 5):

*Hydroponics* is specifically using water (without soil) to grow plants. *Aeroponics* is using air+water (mists, micromisters), no soil, and the roots are usually suspended in the mist.

*Aeroponics* is useful on rooting because the right amount of oxygen and water are available to the roots compared to the sometimes partially anaerobic conditions in traditional hydroponics.

Comment: did you mean "partial anaerobic conditions"?  As water has less available oxygen than air?

Comment: Only if the water is stagnant. Moving water will have plenty of gas exchange.